# How can I count the number of matching values in each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ker', '2', '3', '4'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6', 'ker'], 'C': ['4', '13', '2.5ser','ker'], 'D': ['4', '5', '6','2.5ser']})
df['count'] = df.iloc[0, :].str.count('ker').fillna(0)

print(df)
```

The `count` column ends up filled with `NaN`.

How can I make it so that each value in `count` shows the number of times that `ker` appears in that row?

Comment: What is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The expected logic is unclear, but I imagine you might want:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.count('ker')).sum(axis=1)
```

Note that `count` will count the number of `'ker'` in each string (`'kerxker'` would be 2). If you expect or want to count only one `'ker'` per string use:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('ker')).sum(axis=1)
```

If you want **exact** matches (not substrings), simply use:

```
df['count'] = df.eq('ker').sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B       C       D  count
0  ker    4       4       4      1
1    2    5      13       5      0
2    3    6  2.5ser       6      0
3    4  ker     ker  2.5ser      2
```

Here is another example to show you the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ker', 'kernel', '3', '4'],
                   'B': ['4', '5', '6', 'kerker'],
                   'C': ['4', '13', '2.5ser','ker'],
                   'D': ['4', '5', '6','2.5ser']})

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['count1'] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.count('ker')).sum(axis=1)
df['count2'] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('ker')).sum(axis=1)
df['count3'] = df[cols].eq('ker').sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        A       B       C       D  count1  count2  count3
0     ker       4       4       4       1       1       1
1  kernel       5      13       5       1       1       0
2       3       6  2.5ser       6       0       0       0
3       4  kerker     ker  2.5ser       3       2       1
```

Comment: There are only three hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things (and figuring out what vague question askers actually want 

Comment: @Mark yes, I originally answered based on OP's code, then thought that `count` might not be what they wanted. In the end a more complex answer than initially envisioned ;)

Comment: I read it as getting the sum of each row with "ker" in it! A question not unlike that colour changing dress

Comment: I edited the question on the assumption that you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['count'] = (df == "ker").sum(1)
```

or

```
df['count'] = df.isin(("ker",)).sum(1)
```

---

*The explanation:*

- The `(df == "ker")` comparison, or
- `.isin(("ker",))` method

return a dataframe with the same structure, but only with values `True` or `False`
(as answers to questions *“Is equal to `"ker"`?”* or *“Is in tuple `("ker", )`?”*),

- the `.sum(1)` method then returns a series with number of occurrences of `True` in individual rows (parameter `1` means `axis=1`), because

  - the `True` value is treated as 1,
  - the `False` value is treated as 0.

---

*The result:*

> ```
>      A    B       C       D  count
> 0  ker    4       4       4      1
> 1    2    5      13       5      0
> 2    3    6  2.5ser       6      0
> 3    4  ker     ker  2.5ser      2
> ```