# I need a way to count only certain texts in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['co', '2', 'coco', '4'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6', 'coco'], 'C': ['4', '13', '2.5coco','coco'], 'D': ['4', '5', 'co','2.5co']})

df['count'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('co')).sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Desired result value

I want to know a solution that can only show the number of "co" in the "count" column.

[image]

Comment: I see you ask again the same question, can you say if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76808193/16343464) answers your question, and if not **how this doesn't**. From what you show, my third suggestion `df['count'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].eq('co').sum(axis=1)` does what you want: counting the **exact matches** in a subset of the columns.

Comment: In general, you are expected to comment on answers if you need extra details and to answer request for clarification. Asking again the same question [is not acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339624/16343464).

Comment: The problem was solved with the code you told me.
I heartily thank you.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, then you might want to state that in the other question and also provide the expected output as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76808165/edit) to the original question. This will make things more explicit to future readers.